# Zendesk / ZAF v2 - loading view doesn't work the second time around

Tags: zendesk

I'm experimenting with ZAF V2 and ran into some issues, I'm using the app scaffolding at: https://github.com/zendesk/app_scaffold. I've been looking at documentation and tutorials the last few days with no luck.

I have two files:
**form.hdbs**

```
<form id="myForm"> 
    <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label> 
    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name"> 
    <button class="btn" id="sendBtn">Submit</button>
</form>

Hello {{name}}
```

and **index.js:**

```
import ZAFClient from 'zendesk_app_framework_sdk';
import View from 'view';

var client = ZAFClient.init();
const view = new View();

view.switchTo('form');

$('#sendBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    view.switchTo('form', {
        name: name
    });
});
```

The first time I run the app and type a name / submit, the view reloads and the message shows Hello xxx, the second time I type in a name and hit submit, the app goes blank, no errors in console.

Has anyone run into this issue?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Likely what happened is, the click event fired which rendered the page as you would expect but then the form submits to an empty page. You'd need to avoid the form rendering as well.

This is a "fancy hello world" style app. Most probably once you start actually building a useful app you won't build it like this anyway :)